# Parse cloud job set() function weirdness

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to run this cloud job weekly on parse where I assign a rank to players based on their high scores. This piece of code mostly seems to work except it only sets ranks from 1 to 9. Anything with more than one digit does not get set!
The job returns a success after setting ranks from 1-9.

```js
Parse.Cloud.job("TestJob", function(request, status)
{
 Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
 var rank = 0;
 var usersQuery = new Parse.Query("ECJUser").descending("HighScore"); 
 usersQuery.find(function(results){
  for(var i=0;i<results.length;++i)
  {
   rank += 1;
   console.log("Setting "+results[i].get('Name')+" rank to "+rank);   
   results[i].save({"Rank": rank});
  }
  
 }).then(function(){
  status.success("Weekly Ranks Assigned");
 }, function(error){
  status.error("Uh oh. Weekly ranking failed");
 })  
})
```

In the console log, it clearly says "setting playerName rank to 11", but it doesn't actually set anything in the parse table. Just undefined (or what ever it was previously).

Does the code look right? Something javascript related that I'm missing?

Updated based on answers:
Apparently I'm not waiting for the jobs to complete. But I'm not sure how to write code for handling promises. Here's what I have:

```js
var usersQuery = new Parse.Query("ECJUser").descending("HighScore"); 
 usersQuery.find().then(function(results)
 {
  var promises = [];
  for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
  {
   promises.append(results[i].save({"Rank":rank}));
  }
  return promises;
  
 })
```

What do I do with the list of promises? where do I wait for them to complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not wait for saves to complete so it's going to have unpredictable results. It also isn't going to run through all users, just the first 'page' returned by the query.

So, instead of using `find` you should consider using `each`. You also need to consider wether the job will have time to process all users and may need to run multiple times.

For the save you should add each promise that is returned to an array and then [wait](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Promise.html#methods_when) for all of the promises to complete before calling `status.success`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! 
I tried using `each` but it did not work with my `descending('HighScore')` function. Is there a better way to iterate through a sorted list?

Comment: You can paginate through the `find` and store the offset so you know where you got to

Comment: I'm struggling with the syntax for using promises and waiting for them to complete (I'm used to C# and python).
@Wain, I can't post code in the comment, so I've updated the original question.

Comment: You don't return the array, you want to return a promise, IIRC: `return Parse.Promise.when(promises)`